# MFC customise - add new toolbar?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

In an MFC app, when customising toolbars at runtime, is there an option for users to create their own new toolbars?

I have recently moved my app to the new MFC controls in VS2010.  I was previously using the BCG version of this functionality, which pre-dates VS2008.  (Microsoft bought the BCG stuff and wrapped it in to VS, as of VS2008).  Anyway, I noticed that the Microsoft MFC version does not seem to allow the functionality for users to add their own toolbars under the toolbar customisation.  Users can customise the icons on the toolbars, but the button to add their own new toolbars doesn't seem to be there.

Is there some way to enable this option in my code, so that users can create their own new toolbars?

Answer (score 2):

It is also in the new MFC classes

When I create a new MFC program with the wizard in VS-2010 you can choose this feature on the page "User Interface Features". Select "Use a menu bar and toolbar. There are two further settings "User-defined toolbars and images" and "Personal menu behavior". You have to select the first.

Look into the created code...

HTH

PS: Also the new BCG classes are completely compatible with MFC 2010 and later.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've got an existing app, but I guess I can create two new apps, one with this option ticked, and one without, and then see what the difference in the code is, and replicate that difference in my code.As for the BCG code still working, that's true if you buy the latest BCG code, but my BCG code is a few years old now (pre 2008) and it doesn't build in VS2010.

Comment: Yep, found it, thanks.  It was actually a porting issue from BCG to MFC, but this method allowed me to identify the missing function call to EnableUserDefinedToolbars();